# How to add files to zip or tar without loosing old files using python?

Tags: python, zip, tar, python-zipfile

I want to add files to the zip file using zipfile module i use write() method but each time i add a new file to that zip the old file disappears . But i want to add files to that zip without actually losing any file. And i want to achieve all this with python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a zipfile,

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip','a')
z.write('hello.txt')
z.close()
```

You add a character that signifies how you open that file.
There are many modes for opening a file:
r - open a file in read mode.
w - opens or create a text file in write mode.
a - opens a file in append mode.
etc...

When you opened that zipfile, you must have opened it in 'w' (write) mode, where any changes you make will overwrite your zipfile.

Simply, open you file in 'a' mode.

Comment: bro thanks it really worked i just forget about append because earlier i was working with .tar which also didn't support append THANKS REALLY